# php send a binary response of curl to client

Tags: php, rest, curl, geoserver, wms

I use `php curl` to send a REST request to geoserver and get a binary response.

```
 $curl = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/worksp/wms';
    $query_str = "service=WMS&LAYERS=" . $_GET['LAYERS'] . "&TRANSPARENT=" . $_GET['TRANSPARENT'] . "&VERSION=" . $_GET['VERSION'] . "&REQUEST=" . $_GET['REQUEST'] . "&STYLES=" . $_GET['STYLES'] ;
    $query = $url . '?' . $query_str;
    //var_dump($query);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $query,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false
    ));
    set_time_limit(30);                     // set time in secods for PHP
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:geoserver");
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

the server sends me a png image as a binary data an I save it in the `$response` variable.
Now, `$response` in the above code is a binary data of a png image. how can I send it to client without saving it as a file?
Another question is that, what is the data type of `$response` ?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($response);`

Comment: output of var_dump: PNG ) متی:»«ـ«»«ـ »«ـ«،؛,،آۀّۀآّإإـاتینتامنتیکتیب نتیب اژييآ«ـتاٍٍّريال؛]]؛,؛،ريالٍٍ؛،؛،؛،؛,ٍريالٍريال،

Comment: `echo $response`? maybe with a header() call first to tell the client that you're actually sending a png

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can save the binary data as a file and then send it to the client:

```
// place the above code here
    $saveTo = "c:\\temp.png";
    if (file_exists($saveTo)) {
        unlink($saveTo);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveTo, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $resp);
    fclose($fp);

    header("Content-type:image/png");
    $fp = fopen($saveTo, 'rb');
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit();
```

or you can use `echo`:

```
echo $response;
```

Comment: "without saving it to a file". Why all this file fiddling, when a simple `echo $response` would've done?

Comment: @Dariush Jafari plz,take away your answer. I can`t find any words... I want cry when looking on code above.